# Batch (cmd) script to process all .csv files with sqlite. How to pass file/table names in batch script to sqlite3 call?

Tags: sqlite, csv, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a number of sqlite3 commands in order to generate a .sql file for creating a table from the contents of a csv file.  I want to do this for each .csv file in a directory.  I know this is probably not the ideal way to make a table from a csv file, but somehow this is what it's come to.  I'm completely new to batch/cmd scripting, and new to sqlite as well.  Here's what I have tried, which yields `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b %cd%') do (
sqlite3 ".mode csv" ".import" %%f %%~nf ".output" %%~nf ".sql" ".dump my_table"
)
```

Could something like this work?  I'm sure there is an issue with the way that I'm "passing" file and table names to this slite3 call.  Ideally each iteration of the `for` loop executes a line that looks like:

```
sqlite3 ".mode csv" ".import my_csv.csv my_table" ".output my_table_sql.sql" ".dump my_table"
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: My tip would be to switch from batch to powershell. And/or use [`csvsql`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/3_power_tools.html#csvsql-and-sql2csv-ultimate-power) from csvkit.

Comment: Thanks, ```csvsql``` seems like the ticket...

Comment: BTW, ```for /f %%f in ('dir /b %cd%') do (``` should have been ```For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%f In ('Dir "*.csv" /A:-D-L /B 2^>NUL') Do (```, or possibly just ```For %%f In ("*.csv") Do (```.